# An error occurred while connecting to camera 0: -1 (Operation not permitted)

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, camera

I am doing an app that uses camera2 api to take a picture.
In the onCreate method, the following code causes problem,

```
btnSnap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
     takePicture();
   }
});
```

In the Logcat, there is the error

> W/Camera: An error occurred while connecting to camera 0: -1
>   (Operation not permitted)

But I already give users the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
```

So what is the real problem?

Thank you.

Comment: which version you are targeting ?

Comment: Are you asking for runtime persmission or not ?

Comment: can you post takePicture method

Comment: Thank all of you. I use ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA); to check the permission and then ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},   REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION); to let user allow use the camera. This way solve the problem. Thank you again.